low-gravity wall running
The kind of wallrunning feats in video games such as Mirror's Edge and Prince of Persia depict unrealistic, gravity-defying 3-4 metre horizontal wall runs.
Could this be realistic, however, in an 0.75G world?

Yes, sure. What's the problem for us to solve?

can you wall run 3 m in a .75G world?

More realistic yes, now ask an actual worldbuilding question, like "at what gravity would X feat of wallrunning be possible for X type of person?"

I don't know any princes of Persia, but if you look on YouTube for parkour wall runs you will see that three or four meters up and three or four meters horizontally can be done in our normal gravity. Doing them both at the same time might be a problem.

This comment may come off as deliberatley disingenuous, but I assure you that it isn't. I honestly don't know what you mean by the question after the edit. "In an 0.75G world, how far could an athlete run?" - how far do you want them to be able to run and what's that to do with walls? Can you clarify what the worldbuilding problem to solve is?

Gravity isn't your only factor. Wall running works by friction so depends on how slippy the wall is, or how sticky the footwear. However if you are saying you are reducing gravity by 25% then you can probably wall run for at least 25% more. If the wall is at an angle though then it could be possible for a person to run indefinetly though

If you've the time/inclination, take a look at the Elvis Presley film Roustabout in which he plays a fairground worker who steps-up and performs the "Wall of Death" on a motorcycle - a cylindrical structure. Perhaps needless to say he needs to go dangerously fast to sustain it and comes-off/crashes as a plot-point.

As a note, expert parkourists are able to do this in real life. However, they can't maintain the same height they started with, and slowly descend the wall while running across it. They are also almost as close to parallel and up against the wall as they can get - they aren't sticking out from the wall at anything more than 15-20 degree angles, if they can help it.

I think not really, that wall-climbing would be unrealistic on any small gravity. You can not climb on wall on any small gravity.

Three to four meters?
From Guinness Book of World Records:

The farthest distance wall running is 3.49 m (11 ft 5.4 in) and was
achieved by Amadei Weiland (Germany) on the set of Guinness World
Records – Wir Holen Den Rekord Nach Deutschland, in Europa Park, Rust,
Germany, on 13 July 2012.

https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/farthest-distance-wall-running-(parkour)
Given that is Earth gravity, yes, it could be done in lower gravity. Indeed, someone would be able to go further in lower gravity.
I do not know the equation that would govern how the length changes as gravity changes. If anyone has that, feel free to edit and improve this answer.
